# Main page on main domain, affects subdomain.

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

So I have `www.example.com` and `m.example.com`. Now when I go to `m.example.com` I see the same content as `www.example.com`. I have an `index.php` inside the `m.example.com`, so I'd expect that to show instead.

Here's my `m.website.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName m.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/m/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

And a part of my `apache2.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerAdmin web@webite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/m
    ServerName m.example.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mlog.log
</VirtualHost>
```

So now I'd expect it to work off of `/var/www/m`, and inside that I have a separate file that isn't rendering, because the main domain takes it over. Any help would be great.

Comment: You use 2 places to put your virtualhost ? Both on apache2.conf and on m.website.com.conf ? Why ? What operating system do you have the Apache installed on ?

Comment: Yes I did. Because the tutorial I followed said so.... And Ubuntu 12.04 @AthanasiosEmmanouilidis

Answer (score 1):

For adding virtual hosts to your Apache use this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-debian-7

It's my first time seeing someone that puts virtualhost information on 2 files, both at the `apache2.conf` and at the `sites-available` folder. In my setup, I have an "include" statement in my `apache2.conf` file which includes the files in the `sites-enabled` directory and not other information at all - this is the default for Debian Linux, I didn't touched it at all. I put all my virtualhost configurations in the `sites-available` directory. That's where you should put them also.